# Precedence of to-block unary `&`

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

Consider the following Ruby code:

```
[1,3].any? &:even? || true
# => false
[1,3].any? &nil || :even?
# => false
[1,3].any? &nil || :odd?
# => true
```

So it seems that Boolean-or `||` has higher precedence than to-proc unary `&`. I didn't expect this. Is that right, and is it documented anywhere?

Comment: And yes, I know that the solution is just to stick parens around the `&:even` in the first example.

Comment: A clearer example: `def s;end; s &false || nil`. Returns `nil` but I would expect a TypeError

Comment: as `&` is basically making an argument behave like a block, it seems that it has the same precedence as block which is [the lowest between all other operators](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

Comment: The `||` operator is really, really aggressive.

Comment: @potashin if this was true then `[1,3].any? &:even? or true` would return `false` becuase `or` would have a higher precedent than the block  so `[1,3].any? &(:even? or true) #=> false` but the unary `&` has a higher precedence than `or` and so does the method call to `any?` thus the evaluation is `[1,3].any?(&(:even?)) or true #=> true`

Answer (score 4):

This is what the (wrongly-maligned) `and` and `or` keywords are for. You're supposed to write that as

```
[1,3].any? &:even? or true
```

As for why this happens--I can't find documentation for this--but I think it actually has more to do with optional parentheses and the restrictions of unary &.

Unary `&` is special. "Normal" operators like `~` are essentially syntactic sugar over method calls; you can put them wherever you want. But `&` is *only allowed in method arguments*, and even then only at the end.

```
foo x, &bar
# NameError, determined at runtime because it has to see if any of these names are defined
foo &bar, x
# SyntaxError! Didn't even make it past the parser

y = bar
# NameError
y = &bar
# SyntaxError!
```

And when you leave parentheses out from a method call, it slurps up pretty much everything, stopping only at super-low-precedence stuff like if/unless/and/or.

```
foo bar baz if true
# same as
foo(bar(baz)) if true
```

So your example is equivalent to

```
[1,3].any?(&:even? || true)
```

Now if `&` were somehow high-precendence this is either a totally normal value to be evaluated at runtime `true` or it's a highly-restricted special syntactic construct `&:even?`. It's not great to discover syntax errors at runtime, so I guess the devs chose to solve it the easy way: make `&` super low precedence. That way the parser can just verify the syntax rules and ignore the block argument itself (which has to be evaluated at runtime).

Comment: I need to digest the last few paras here. I'll just clarify that `and` and `or` is not what I'm wanting - I had distilled down an example which was actually more like `if my_array.any? &:predicate? || other_condition`, which fired or not based only on the `any?`

Comment: That has nothing to do with blocks, that's just optional parentheses biting you: `if foo bar || baz` is `if foo(bar || baz)`

Comment: @Chowlett and `or` would fix that bug as well: `if my_array.any? &:predicate or other_condition` does what you would expect. Though I'd prefer parens since that looks a bit confusing.

Comment: You should not be using `and` and `or` for Boolean combinations, only flow control. And yeah, the fix is obviously to add parens. The point about method-call being greedy is relevant, of course.

Comment: @Max operational and (`&`) is a method call but has a higher precendence than logical or (`||`)  [see my post for examples]. So this seems to fall outside of  *"...it slurps up pretty much everything, stopping only at super-low-precedence stuff like if/unless/and/or"*. Otherwise I would anticipate things like `true & nil || :even?` to be parsed as `true.&(nil || :even?) #=> true` but instead you get `true.&(nil) || :even? #=> :even?`

Comment: @engineersmnky My point isn't that unary `&` isn't a method call (maybe it is?). My point is that it doesn't behave like other operators because it is only valid in a very specific context, which is enforced at the parsing stage. It _has_ to have the lowest precedence in that context because otherwise the interpreter wouldn't know ahead of time whether or not an argument represents a block.

Comment: @max I agree that it is not a method call although it appears to be a mechanism to facilitate one. However clearly it does not have the lowest precedent otherwise your initial example would not work correctly. Not exactly sure where it falls from a precedent standpoint or even how to test such a thing

Answer (score 0):

When the `&` is not preceded by an object (unary) and is immediately followed by by anything else (`&nil` in this case). It will be parsed as an attempted `to_proc` method call otherwise it will be treated as a method call on the receiver e.g.

```
 nil&nil
 #=> false
```

Is equivalent to `nil.&(nil)`

So in your case (`[1,3].any? &nil || :even?`) it is being parsed as `[1,3].any?(&(nil || :even?))` because `&` (`to_proc` method call) has a lower precedence than logical `||` and needs to know the result of `nil || :even?` to proceed.

However, operational and (`&`) requires a receiver (not unary) but does hold a higher precedence than the logical or (`||`)  e.g. `[1,3].any? &nil&nil || :even?` which would evaluate to

```
[1,3].any?(&(nil.&(nil) || :even?)
#=> false
# Or
[1,3].any?(&(nil & nil || :even?)
#=> false
```

Where strangely enough it is clear that operational and (`&`) has a higher precedence than logical or (`||`)

Further examples

```
true & nil || :even? 
#=> :even?

true & :even? 
#=> true

[1,3].any? &true&true || :even?
#=> TypeError: wrong argument type TrueClass (expected Proc)

# Okay no problem

class TrueClass
  def to_proc
    ->(*_) { true } 
  end
end 

[1,3].any? &true&true || :even?
#=> true
[1,3].any? &true || :even?
#=> true
```

Even stranger is that the unary `&` allows for `nil` but essentially ignores it from `block_given?` but any other object that does not implement `to_proc` raises a `TypeError`

```
def no_block
  block_given? ? yield('Yes') : 'No'
end

no_block &nil
#=> "No"

no_block &false
#=> TypeError: wrong argument type FalseClass (expected Proc)
```

Comment: I think the reason it works with `nil` is because it could be `&var`, and then there needs to be some way to set `var` such that `block_given?` is false. A special exception, but a necessary one.

Comment: @Max I agree that it is a strange but necessary evil where by `&nil == nil` in the context of a method argument where by `def block_is_nil?(&block); block == nil; end` such that `block_is_nil?(&nil) #=> true`